# visual studio express 2012 how to package an app? phonegap

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, package

I created a phonegap app in VS2012 express and I have the app running on my device and emulation but I cannot figure out how to create a .appx or .appxupload file to upload to the windows store. I tried following every tutorial I could but my VS2012 does not have any of the windows/tools they talk about. There is no Project->Store (I even looked at the customize menu and its not listed anywhere as an option), and when I open a manifest file there are 3 tabs (application ui, capabilities, packaging) however there are no options on any of those tabs to actually create a package only configuration options. Has anyone else ran into this? Can you not do this using VS2012 express? If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is the output of your app project? that itself should be an .appx. maybe share the build output logs here.

Comment: It is an .xap which microsft doesn't take as an upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment you have created a phone app. You should be uploading it to the windows phone store. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206723(v=vs.105).aspx

The appx is what is expected for Windows 8 Store targeted for the desktop/tablet. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230835.aspx#build_package

Make sure you are uploading your stuff in the right store.

Comment: Thank you, I did not even realize it was a separate store I thought the app type determined placement. Looks like my developer account is also in the wrong area, hope they can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried their Build product? You zip up your code, upload to them, and they compile it for you in all platforms it supports.

https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

> There is no Project->Store (I even looked at the customize menu and its not listed anywhere as an option)

Confusing isn't isn't it? "Project" doesn't mean the "Project" menu.

Go to Solution Explorer. At the top level you have your solution. At the second level you have one or more projects. Right click on the right project and you will get a whole bunch of other options, one of which is "Store". That is the one you want.